# OSX 10.6.8 Xcode 4.2 Change Created and Modified Dates

Tags: xcode, shell, applescript, osx-snow-leopard

I've been working on an Applescript to change the creation and modification dates of a particular file via (do shell script).  The first script with a manually input date works fine, but the second script which uses the (current date command) with an appended time, throws an error code, even though the output from both scripts appears to be the same.  Any help would be most appreciated.

### Script #1

```
resetFile()
on resetFile()
    do shell script "SetFile -d '02/18/2016 00:01:00' ~/Desktop/Test.txt"
    do shell script "SetFile -m '02/18/2016 00:01:00' ~/Desktop/Test.txt"
end resetFile
```

### Script #2

```
resetFile()
on resetFile()
    set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to (current date)
    set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to result
    if (d * 1) < 10 then
        if (m * 1) < 10 then
            set dateTime to quoted form of ("0" & m * 1 & "/" & "0" & d * 1 & "/" & y * 1 & " " & "00:01:00") as string
    else
        set dateTime to quoted form of (m * 1 & "/" & "0" & d * 1 & "/" & y * 1 & " " & "00:01:00") as string
    end if
else
    if (m * 1) < 10 then
        set dateTime to quoted form of ("0" & m * 1 & "/" & d * 1 & "/" & y * 1 & " " & "00:01:00") as string
    else
        set dateTime to quoted form of (m * 1 & "/" & d * 1 & "/" & y * 1 & " " & "00:01:00") as string
    end if
end if
display dialog dateTime
do shell script "SetFile -d dateTime ~/Desktop/Test.txt"
do shell script "SetFile -m dateTime ~/Desktop/Test.txt"
end resetFile
```

[image: Dialog dateTime]

[image: Error Code]

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler version to create the date string. It uses a handler to add leading zeros if needed:

```
resetFile()
on resetFile()
    set {year:y, month:m, day:d} to (current date)
    set dateTime to quoted form of (pad(m as integer) & "/" & pad(d) & "/" & y & space & "00:01:00")

    display dialog dateTime
    do shell script "SetFile -d " & dateTime & " ~/Desktop/Test.txt"
    do shell script "SetFile -m " & dateTime & " ~/Desktop/Test.txt"
end resetFile

on pad(v)
    return text -2 thru -1 of ((v + 100) as text)
end pad
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, your script has the same issue that mine had.  The problem with both of our scripts deals with inserting an Applescript variable into a shell script.


Incorrect:

do shell script "SetFile -d dateTime ~/Desktop/Test.txt"

Correct :

do shell script "SetFile -d " & dateTime & " ~/Desktop/Test.txt"

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. I updated my answer to the proper way to pass AS variables